# Basic trigonometry (drawing a line)

Tags: java, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw a recursive tree, but I'm already stuck at the beginning. I've been trying to figure this out, for a while now, and I just can't seem to get it right.

I am using the StdDraw library. Here's what I want to do:

[image]

I've already drawn the trunk (black line). But I need to draw the red line too.

In the main function I've set the canvas size to 500x500px and I've set the x and y limit from 0-500.

```
StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);
StdDraw.setScale(0, 500);
```

The tree parameters that I receive are the tree length (d) and the angle (sine). There are also some others (needed for recursion, but not relevant for this simple problem)

I've drawn the trunk using the following code:

```
StdDraw.line(250, 150, 250, 150+d);
```

If you're not familiar with StdDraw it's: `StdDraw.line(x0, y0, x1, y1)`

Now for the red line I've been struggling with some basic trigonometry, but I don't know where I'm wrong. Here's the code:

```
//The length of the red line is 3/4 the length of the trunk(given in instructions)
double hypotenuse = (3/4)*d;
//We get the opposite by multiplying the sine * hypotenuse, correct?
double opposite = Math.sin(alpha) * hypotenuse;
//Pythagorean Theorem to get the adjacent
double adjacent = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(hypotenuse, 2)-Math.pow(opposite, 2));
//We draw the line from the last x position minus adjacent to move to the left 
//and from last y position upwards by 150+d(previous position)+opposite    
StdDraw.line(250,150+d,250-adjacent,150+d+opposite);
```

I create a new Tree object in main with `d=110, alpha=40` to test it.

If I remove the trunk and only try to draw the red line (using `StdDraw.line(250,150+d,250-adjacent,150+d+opposite)`). I only get a black dot, like this:

[image]

Comment: Which angle are you considering as `alpha`? What is the value of it? Did you try checking the resulting values of `opposite` and `adjacent`?

Comment: @kaykay Alpha is 40 degrees and sine value is 0.7451131604793488. I've checked for opposite, adjacent, and hypotenuse and they are all 0. I feel dumb, not checking this before, but now that I know that seems to be the problem, I have no idea why are they all 0? Any ideas?

Comment: These are the value I got with the provided information `hypotenuse = 82.5`, `opposite = 61.47`, `adjacent = 55.02`, `x0 = 250`, `y0 = 260`, `x1 = 194.98`, `y1 = 321.47`.  They looks Ok, don't you have a function to move to an start point and after that draw the line

Comment: dividing with int values ?

Comment: Yes, `double hypotenuse = (3/4)*d;` - `3/4` is going to equal `0`.

Comment: `d = 110` and `alpha = 40` according to the information. @mythic said *"I create a new Tree object in main with d=110, alpha=40 to test it."*

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Oh god, I didn't know that.. I googled it now and it seems that this is a feature? I've changed it to 3.0/4.0 and it works now. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your sides are getting set to zero, because here:

```
double hypotenuse = (3/4)*d;
```

`(3/4)` equals `0`. Change to:

```
double hypotenuse = (3/4.0)*d;
```

or:

```
double hypotenuse = 0.75 * d;
```

Comment: Yeah like I've said in the comment above, that fixed the problem. Thanks again